# highcharts- stacked bar, how can I make the chart cover the width 100%?

Tags: highcharts

I have created a chart in jsfiddle which represents two values. id like the stacked bar chart to be adjusted so that it takes the whole width of the div. it should cover the background, like so.

http://jsfiddle.net/ftaran/jBHDM/4/

[image]

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            background:'yellow'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }

        },
        yAxis: {
            title: null,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + ':</b> ' + this.y + '<br/>' + this.percentage.toFixed(2) + '%';
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Fail',
            color: 'red',
            data: [5]
        }, {
            name: 'Success',
            color: 'green',
            data: [2]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this `yAxis` parameter:

```
yAxis: {
     ...
     endOnTick: false,
     ...
},
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible to toggle the endOnTick value when an event is raised.for example a button click?

Comment: @xerxes, yes you can toggle it via a command from a button click. Use the axis.update method. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/jBHDM/7/

Answer (score 1):

Just complementing [@wergeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33727/wergeld)'s answer. If you still haven't gotten the result expected after applying his suggestion:

```js
yAxis: {
  max: totalOfSeriesData
}
```

Per example:

```js
  series: [
      {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5],
        color: 'red',
      },
      {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2],
      },
      {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3],
      },
    ],

yAxis: {
  max: 10, // 5 + 2 + 3 = 10
  endOnTick: false,
}
```

Comment: Setting [max](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max) it's appropriate options to set the bar to the end of the chart, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/70ezgj1a/).